# Large empty bordered cells in tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

I am trying to build a worksheet for students and I am having difficulty getting my table to behave the way I want it to. I am trying to build a large empty cell, which I mostly have using `\multicolumn`, but my borders along the sides are broken when I try to add `\vspace`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l | p{0.4\textwidth} |}
    \hline
    Point 1: \hspace{0.3\textwidth} & Point 2: \vspace{2cm}\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\vspace{5cm}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: replace `{\vspace{5cm}} \\ ` by `{}\\[5cm]`

Comment: I would replace `{\vspace{5cm}}` with `{\rule{0pt}{5cm}}`

Comment: You should use `{|p{.8\textwidth}|}` or similar in your `\multicolumn` command if you want vertical spacing commands to behave properly. Given what the tabular ends up looking like, you could make the left column a `p{.4\textwidth}` also.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Care to answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
{}\\[5cm]
```

Not

```
 {\vspace{5cm}}
```

the optional vertical space argument of `\\` is defined in a way specifically not to break vertical rules. (Which means incidentally it doesn't always add the space that people expect, but it will work well enough here).